# Regex pattern(Java) to identify the start of oracle with clause

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match the pattern to identify the start of oracle WITH clause definition. So far I have the following pattern, but it's failing. Can anybody point out the problem?

(WITH|with)(\s)+[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9] (\s)+(AS|as)

Test cases:

1. WITH  dept_count   AS
2. WITH FD_DFDF_DF AS
3. with deddd23 AS
4. WITH FD_DFDF_DF as

Comment: Don't use regular expressions as parsers. Use parsers as parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need repetition of the second alphanumeric group and remove the whitespace:

```
(WITH|with)(\s)+[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s)+(AS|as)
```

Test it:
https://regex101.com/r/jZ9gM5/1

Answer (score 1):

try (WITH|with)(\s)+[_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s)+(AS|as)

Comment: Since identifiers cannot start with numbers this cannot be used, I should've added a test case for that, thanks anyway